# Extending a class hierarchy in Python

Tags: python

I have a class hierarchy in a module that I want to extend.

The module to be extended looks something like this.
Module foo:

```
class bar(object): pass
class spam(bar): pass
class eggs(bar): pass
```

Now I want to extend these classes:

```
class my_bar(foo.bar):
    def new_func(): pass
class my_spam(foo.spam): pass
class my_eggs(foo.eggs): pass
```

Doing so, a new function new_func() in my_bar would not be available in a my_spam instance using

```
my_spam_instance.new_func()
```

What is the best ("most pythonic") way to achieve this? I thought of multiple inheritance, like this:

```
class my_bar(foo.bar): pass
class my_spam(foo.bar, my_bar): pass
class my_eggs(foo.eggs, my_bar): pass
```

Though I never really used it before and I am not sure this is the best way.

Comment: What you wrote should work, but the "diamond relationship" (my_spam inherits from foo.bar and my_bar, both inherit from bar) can make things difficult to understand. You could let my_bar not inherit from foo.bar (mixin). Can you give some context on the classes you want to extend?

Comment: Based on the details you present here, multiple inheritance (MI) should work out great for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to inherit `my_bar` from `bar`

*pythonic* will be adding Mixin, which is actually a base class, but not inherited

```
class NewFuncMixin():
    def new_func(): pass
```

And add it to new classes

```
class my_bar(foo.bar, NewFuncMixin): pass
class my_spam(foo.spam, NewFuncMixin): pass
class my_eggs(foo.eggs, NewFuncMixin): pass
```

Comment: This sounds pretty good. But how do I call both __init__ methods from foo.spam and NewFuncMixin inside my_spam.__init__()? Can I use super() for that or do I have to call them explicitly (like foo.spam.__init__() and NewFuncMixin.__init__())?

Comment: only the first base   `__init__` is called automatically if the derived class does not have it. so basically you can explicitly call it in derived `__init__`  :

  ```NewFuncMixin.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  ```

Answer (score 0):

What about a mixin class? The pattern is

```
class My_mixin( object):
   def new_func(self): pass

class My_spam( My_mixin, foo.spam):  pass
class My_eggs( My_mixin, foo.eggs):  pass
```

mixins should inherit from object, and go on the left of the inheritance list so that the mixin class methods get name priority. Within the mixin you can then wrap any method of the superclass:

```
class My_mixin( object):

   def bar_method( self):
      # stuff
      bar_result = super( My_mixin, self).bar_method()
      # more stuff
      return bar_result # or my_result based on bar_result
```

You can of course completely override the method instead of wrapping it.